# Count rows dynamically based on some criteria in R/python

Tags: python, r, dynamic

I have a Dataset with 2.5 million data with the following sample data.

```
id   status    count    webiste         source
1     True       0     www.test.com      Accurate
2     True       1     www.true.com      Need Test
3     False      2     Null              Accurate
4     False      100   Null              Need Test
```

id  - unique value

Status - True/False

Count - 0-10000

Webiste - contains url else  null

source -  Accurate / Need to be tested

It also other columns with number range from 0-1000 and so.

I want to show the options of slider for number columns and dropdown for other columns to the user.

I want to select count of subset of data with the specifications from user.

Eg : count with Status as True and contains website and contains website.

These specifications will be given by user. These need to be done in R or python?

Comment: study sub-setting in r. however your answer `library(dplyr);data%>%filter(status=="True",count>=1,!webiste== "Null",source=="Need Test")`

Comment: I have used filter from dplyr but it is static. We need to specify the criteria. I want to take criteria from user and filter on it. And supply this selection page to user, upon his selection it should return the count to him.

Comment: you can use a function.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example to get you started. This will count the number of rows where the website field is not NA, the status is `TRUE`, and the count is between 30 and 100

```
nrow(dataset[!is.na(dataset$website) & dataset$status == TRUE & dataset$count >= 30 & dataset$count <= 100, ])
```

Note that each of the conditions is effectively retaining only those rows that meet the condition. But note if R is unsure whether a row meets your critera (because it has an NA), then it will *return* it. E.g. if we knew we had some status values that are NA (and we didn't want to count those), then we should adapt the code as follows:

```
nrow(dataset[!is.na(dataset$website) & (dataset$status == TRUE & !is.na(dataset$status)) & dataset$count >= 30 & dataset$count <= 100, ])
```

One more tip: don't forget the comma before the last square brace

Now, to make this dynamic (i.e. to accept user input), you can simply replace the hard-coded values with the user input, like so

```
user_selected_status <- TRUE
user_selected_min_count <- 30
user_selected_max_count <- 100

nrow(dataset[!is.na(dataset$website) & (dataset$status == user_selected_status & !is.na(dataset$status)) & dataset$count >= user_selected_min_count & dataset$count <= user_selected_max_count, ])
```

Comment: I want to supply the options to the user and upon their selection I want the count with their criteria. The solution you have provided is static

Comment: @shashank I have adjusted the example to show how you can pass user input to the subsetting syntax

Comment: It should be dropdown and slider selection

Comment: @shashank Ah I see. You can accept user input through an R package called shiny, it is a little more complicated than running a standard R script, so allow an hour or so to learn how a basic shiny app works, but it's definitely possible with shiny. Also, [shinyapps.io](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html) makes it extremely easy to deploy anything you make to the web if that's your end game

Comment: I can do it with r shiny but I cannot provide it to the user without deploying it. I don't have any server to deploy it.I want to provide it to the user as html or file where he can select options and get the result count

Comment: @shashank allow you to deploy one app for free, for a certain number of hours per month (I think it sleeps after 10 minutes of inactivity, so the free hours usually last much longer than you think - in any case it's a great way to see it in action). Once you have something working on your laptop, it takes about 10 minutes to get it on to the web

Comment: The data is confidential so uploading it on web may be problem